# Объединение полигона и окружности на карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

На карте нарисован полигон и несколько окружностей на угла полигона. Требуется объединить их в одну фигуру. Поиск по api ничего толком не дал, в интернетах говорят, что такое не реализовано (на 2016 год). Есть ли на сегодняшний день какие-нибудь способы объединения разных фигур?

Answer (score 1):

Метода, который позволит это сделать из коробки в Апи Яндекс карт нет. Его нужно реализовать самостоятельно.